# select km difference of a vehicle beween from date to Todate in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
 VEHICLE_ID, 
 DRIVER_ID,
 SUM(AMOUNT) as Total_Amount, 
 SUM(ODOMETER) as Total_Odometer, 
 SUM(LTR) As Total_Ltr
FROM Fuel_Filling 
WHERE 
COMPANY_ID = @COMPANY_ID 
AND VEHICLE_ID = @VEHICLE_ID
 AND DATE_TIME BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE 
GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID, DRIVER_ID
```

I want to select ODOMETER Between Dates

Comment: What is wrong with the query?

Comment: Does not wrong anything but i want to select ODOMETER Difference between Dates

Answer (score 3):

If ODOMETER is truly the odometer reading then this should work:

```
SELECT 
 VEHICLE_ID, 
 DRIVER_ID,
 SUM(AMOUNT) as Total_Amount, 
 MAX(ODOMETER) - MIN(ODOMETER) as DistanceTravelled, 
 SUM(LTR) As Total_Ltr
FROM Fuel_Filling 
 WHERE 
 COMPANY_ID = @COMPANY_ID 
 AND VEHICLE_ID = @VEHICLE_ID
 AND DATE_TIME BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE 
 GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID, DRIVER_ID
```

Comment: @user2732906 make sure you accept valid answers to your questions (not just this one but your others as well) as you will be more likely to get folks to help out :)